# Launch an implicit intent at the same time as an explicit attempt and finish the activity

Tags: android, android-intent

In my app, one of the options available to users who are authenticated is to delete their account. When they select this option, I want to do three things:

1. Launch an implicit intent to go to a website, e.g. to take a survey or something
2. Launch an explicit intent to go to the intro/splash activity of the app
3. Finish the current activity

This is the click handler for the "delete account" button:

```
val intent1 = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, "http://...")
startActivity(intent1)

val intent2 = Intent(this, IntroActivity::class.java)
intent2.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)
startActivity(intent2)
finish()
```

What's actually happening is the intro/splash activity starts and the current activity finishes, but the browser doesn't launch. I don't know if the flags are really necessary for the explicit intent.

If I reverse the order of events in the click handler, it seems to work on a hardware phone but not in the emulator for some reason:

```
val intent2 = Intent(this, IntroActivity::class.java)
intent2.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)
startActivity(intent2)
finish()

val intent1 = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, "http://...")
startActivity(intent1)
```

My question is twofold: why is it behaving this way and what's the correct way to do it?

Comment: "why is it behaving this way" -- clearing a task clears the task. The `ACTION_VIEW` activity would be part of your task, and so you would clear it. "what's the correct way to do it?" -- don't delegate "a survey or something" to another app. Handle it in-app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't launch 2 intents simultaneously.  One of them takes preference, and the other is dropped (I'm not sure if which is ignored is consistent across versions, so I won't comment there).  You need to launch the query/survey, then launch the next intent in response.  Or launch your home screen with some extra that tells it to then launch the browser (so you logout, goto home, then the browser launches).  You cannot do it as 2 straight startActivity calls.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`startActivities`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#startActivities(android.content.Intent[],%20android.os.Bundle)) method which takes in an array of `Intents` and an optional bundle of extras.

Answer (score 0):

Use startActivities instead of startActivity:

```
val intent1 = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, "http://...")
val intent2 = Intent(this, IntroActivity::class.java)
intent2.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)
val intents = arrayOf<Intent>(intent2, intent1)
startActivities(intents)
finish()
```

Put intent in last in array which need to display on top.